# Javascript check if two File objects point to the same file

Tags: javascript, filelist

I have two arrays of File (File web API) objects that I want to compare, but I can't figure out which properties I could use to do it.

The arrays can become pretty large so I don't want to have to compare the file content. Actually even having to read the file would be a huge constraint... What else would be a good way to check if two File objects reference the same file? Note that they can be in different paths, so the filenames might not be unique...

Comment: And which properties do you have in a file object?

Comment: What about the arrays buffer length when you read a file? Maybe those two can be compared?

Comment: I'd check against the size, type and last modified date ...

Comment: If the files can be in different paths under different names, then I’d assume that the last modified date probably can’t be relied upon to be the same for two “identical” files. That leaves checking for size & type, and then in those cases where you get a match for those two, you might need to actually compare the file contents, at least partially …

Comment: @NurbolAlpysbayev it's the File object from the File web API: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/File

Comment: @gugateider thanks, that might be the best I can do. Too bad that there is no solution built in